# Leer archivo Excel con PhpSpreadsheet

Tags: php

Necesito leer mi archivo Excel con la librería *PhpSpreadsheet*, pero obtengo el siguiente error:

> ```
> File "archivo.xlxs" does not exist.
> File: phpoffice/phpspreadsheet/src/PhpSpreadsheet/Shared/File.php
> ```

El siguiente codigo es mi `DbHandler.php`:

```
 <?php
# Cargar clases instaladas por Composer
require __DIR__ . "/vendor/autoload.php";
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet;

 $ruta = "archivo.xlsx";
 $spreadsheet = IOFactory::load($ruta);
?>
```

Mi archivo `archivo.xlsx` sí existe en la ruta donde esta mi `DBHandler.php` y sí tiene datos.

Comment: ¿Coincide exactamente en mayúsculas/minúsculas? Además, comprueba que tu error marca un nombre de archivo diferente (`archivo.xlxs` <> `archivo.xlsx`). La extensión cambia entre el mensaje de error y el nombre del archivo del código PHP. Alguno de los dos lo tienes mal.

Comment: Ok listo ya arregle la extension del archivo sin embargo sigo obteniendo el mismo error ahora con File "archivo.xlsx" does not exist.

Comment: ¿Comprobaste lo primero que te dije? ¿Comprobaste que coincidía el nombre de archivo y directorio? ¿Qué framework estás usando? ¿En qué directorio está tu enrutador y en qué directorio el código PHP y el archivo? ¿Has probado con `$ruta = __DIR__ ."/archivo.xlsx";`?